# Creating multithreading java class to process data

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

I would like to realize class in Java, which will be wait for new data from different threads and when he got it, this class will process it and again go to wait new data. I want to realize this using only **synchronized, wait, notifyAll** commands. I tried some variants:

1) using one thread, which wait by command lockObject.wait(). But when all active threads finish their work, this thread will be waiting forever. Of course, I can make method stopProcess(), but it is not safety, because another programmer can forget to call it.

2) using one daemon-thread, it will not work, because when all active threads finish their work, my daemon-thread die, but he can have some data which he must to process

3)when new data is coming - create new thread, which will process data. while thread is alive(he process given data), he will receive new data. when it is no data coming and all old data was processed, thread finish to work. Minus of this variant is - when data is coming through some period (when thread have time to process old data and die), a new thread will be created. I think it's bad for performance or/and memory. Am I right?

Is it possible to solve my problem using only one or two(may be using daemon and active thread in combination) threads and not using stopProcess() method??

Here some code

My realize of blocking queue

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {
    private Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void add(T el){
        synchronized (queue){
            queue.add(el);
        }
    }

    public T getFirst(){
        synchronized (queue){
            return queue.poll();
        }
    }

    public int getSize(){
        synchronized (queue){
            return queue.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Data class

```
public class Data {
    //some data

    public void process(){
        //process this data
    }
}
```

First variant of code

```
public class ProcessData {

    private BlockingQueue<Data> queue = new BlockingQueue<Data>();
    private boolean run = false;
    private Thread processThread;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public synchronized void addData(Data data) throws Exception {
        if (run){
            if (data != null){
                queue.add(data);
                wakeUpToProcess();
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (!run){
            run = true;

            processThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    while (run || queue.getSize()!=0){

                        while(queue.getSize() == 0 && run){
                            //if stopProcess was not called
                            //and no active threads
                            //it will not die
                            waitForNewData();
                        }

                        Data cur;
                        while(queue.getSize() > 0){
                            cur = queue.getFirst();
                            cur.process();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
            processThread.start();

        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopProcess() {
        if (run){
            run = false;
            wakeUpToProcess();
        }
    }

    private void waitForNewData(){
        try{
            synchronized (lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void wakeUpToProcess(){
        synchronized (lock){
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

In second variant I make processThread as daemon. But when active threads die, processThread finish to work, but there are some data in queue, which i have to process.

Third variant

```
public class ProcessData {

    private BlockingQueue<Data> queue = new BlockingQueue<Data>();
    private boolean run = false;
    private Thread processThread = null;

    public synchronized void addData(Data data) throws Exception {
        if (run){
            if (data != null){
                queue.add(data);
                wakeExecutor();
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception("ProcessData is stopped!");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (!run){
            run = true;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopProcess() {
        if (run){
            run = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning(){
        return this.run;
    }

    protected void wakeExecutor(){
        if (processThread ==null || !processThread.isAlive()){
            processThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Data cur;
                    while(queue.getSize() > 0){
                        cur = queue.getFirst();
                        cur.process();
                    }
                }
            });
            processThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

It is important, that data must to process in the order, in which it come from threads.

Comment: Please write what you have tried in the code.

Comment: What's wrong with the daemon which spawns a new thread for each request?  (Kind of like a web server...)

Comment: @bdares The process order of data is important. First data have to be  processed, and when process is finished - second data can be processed. And so on...

Comment: Is this a homework question? Is there a particular reason why you can't just use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`?

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes, it is like homework question=) I can't use concurrent package=(

Answer (score 1):

You are seriously reinventing the wheel here. All you want is available in the JDK in the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Implement a [producer-consumer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) via a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), with your producers calling [`offer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29) and your consumer thread calling [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29), which blocks until something's available.

That's it. You don't need, and you shouldn't be writing, all those classes you have written. These concurrent classes do all the locking and synchronization for you, and do it *correctly* too (which is not to be underestimated)

Comment: I know, that concurrent package solve all my problems, but I can't use it. It is my homework question

Comment: Does my first variant implement producer-consumer pattern?(ProcessData class as consumer class)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use anything from `java.util.concurrent` then you'll have to implement your own task queue based on something like a `LinkedList`.  I would encapsulate the blocking behaviour in the queue, e.g. (pseudocode)

```
synchronized Data nextTask() {
  while(the linked list is empty) {
    wait()
  }
  remove and return head of the queue
}

synchronized void addTask(Data d) {
  add d to the queue
  notifyAll()
}
```

Then you can just have a consumer thread that continuously does something like this

```
while(true) {
  taskQueue.nextTask().process()
}
```

and the producer threads call `taskQueue.addTask` to add each task to the queue.  If you need a graceful shutdown at the end then you'll either need some "sentinel value" to tell the consumer thread to finish, or find some way of calling `Thread.interrupt()` at the right time.